# Carcass of QProgressDialog lingers - sometimes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

```
    progress = QtGui.QProgressDialog("Parsing Log", "Stop", 0,numberOfLinesInFile , self)
    progress.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)

    for lineNumber, line in enumerate(file):
        # yield a bit to the Qt UI handler
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
        progress.setValue(lineNumber + 1) # lineNumber is zero-based so need the plus one to match the more literal numberOfLinesInFile
        if progress.wasCanceled():
            progressWasCancelled = True
            break


        # ...read and parse lines from file (20mb takes ~10 seconds)


    # crank the progress bar through to completion to get rid of it
    # this seems to forgo the opportunity to use progress.wasCanceled() subsequently?
    progress.setValue(numberOfLinesInFile)


    if not progressWasCancelled:
        self.updateTable(self.requestRoster)
```

After this, and regardless of the progress dialogue being cancelled or not, the progress dialogue is hidden (it slides back up into the toolbar).  But if I switch application ('command tab' on the Mac) then switch back to my application, a ghost of the QProgressDialog is in front of the main application window!  Its progress bar is at 100% and the stop button is blue but not pulsing.  It is unresponsive.  If I move the application window it disappears.

If I call progress.destroy() after progress.setValue(numberOfLinesInFile) that seems to help.  But it seems worrying to copy the example from the docs and get bitten, and I don't know the ramifications of destroy().

I was using PySide, I switched to PyQt and same thing.

Also, sometimes `progress.setValue(numberOfLinesInFile)` causes subsequent reads of `progress.wasCancelled()` to return false (but sometimes it returns true!) which is why I set my own `progressWasCancelled`.  Its randomness is disturbing.

I'm on Mac 10.6.8, Qt 4.8.2, Python 2.7.  Tried with PySide 1.1.0 and PyQt 4.9.4.

Am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: Please don't ask two unrelated questions in one. You should post the part about the progress bar as a separate question.

Comment: @satuon. There definitely aren't two unrelated questions here, so I've rolled your edit back. Without going into too much detail, the `setValue()` function in a progress dialog does a *lot* more than just update the progress bar widget.

Answer (score 5):

I can't test on a Mac, but I'll try to make a few suggestions which could help solve your issues.

Firstly, if you use a *modal* progress dialog, there's no need to call `processEvents()`, as the dialog will handle this itself.

Secondly, this line in your code:

```
    progress.setValue(lineNumber + 1)
```

is problematic, because to quote the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#value-prop):

> For the progress dialog to work as expected, you should **initially set this property to 0** and **finally set it to QProgressDialog::maximum()**; you can call setValue() any number of times in-between.

so you should either call `progress.setValue(0)` before the loop, or just avoid adding the offset altogether. Also, on the final iteration, `lineNumber + 1` will equal the maximum, which will [reset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#reset) the dialog at that point (unless [autoReset](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#autoReset-prop) has been set to False). It is for this reason that the Qt example calls `setValue(maximum)` *after* the loop has completed.

Finally, there is no problem with calling `destroy()` or `deleteLater()` after you've finished with the progress dialog - in fact, it's a good idea. When you pass `self` to the QProgressDialog constructor, it will become the parent of the dialog and *keep a reference to it*. So, unless you explicitly delete it, a new child dialog (plus all it's child objects) will be added every time you call the function that uses it (which could potentially waste a lot of memory).

Here's a demo script that may be improvement:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        file = range(30)
        numberOfLinesInFile = len(file)
        progressWasCancelled = False
        progress = QtGui.QProgressDialog(
            "Parsing Log", "Stop", 0, numberOfLinesInFile, self)
        progress.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        progress.setMinimumDuration(0)
        for lineNumber, line in enumerate(file):
            progress.setValue(lineNumber)
            if progress.wasCanceled():
                progressWasCancelled = True
                break
            time.sleep(0.05)
        progress.setValue(numberOfLinesInFile)
        print 'cancelled', progress.wasCanceled(), progressWasCancelled
        progress.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```